# When using popd, how to push the current directory onto the stack?

Tags: shell, pushd

When using `popd`, how to push the current directory onto the stack?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ pwd; pushd /tmp; pwd; popd; pwd
/home/users/foo
/tmp ~
/tmp
~
/home/users/foo
```

> Bash will keep a history of the directories you visit, you just have to ask.
>   Bash stores the history in a stack and uses the commands pushd
>   and popd to manage the stack.

If you don't need multiple levels of directory history, you can also do:

```
cd foo
# do your stuff in foo
cd -
```

Compared to `pushd`/`popd`, this has the disadvantage that if `cd foo` fails, you end up in the wrong directory with `cd -`.

(Probably `cd -` is more handy outside scripts. "Let's go back where I just was.")

See [Use pushd and popd to manipulate directory stack](http://linux.101hacks.com/cd-command/dirs-pushd-popd/) for more help.

Comment: I also advise the OP to google around for the concept of stack, and the push and pop operations in programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

It should be just

```
[$]> pushd .
```

no?

Answer (score 0):

```
pushd -n $(pwd)
```

adds the current directory `$(pwd)` to the stack without changing directory.

From `help pushd` in bash:

> Options:
>
> `-n`  Suppresses the normal change of directory when adding directories to the stack, so only the stack is manipulated.